Why does the “match” function not work in this particular situation?
I have the 57-byte text file (in UTF-8). It can be generated by the following command:
echo '3C6469763E3C6469763E5F3C2F6469763E5F3C68313E6162636465665F3C2F68313E5F3C2F6469763E3C6469763EF09F93853C2F6469763E0A' | xxd -r -p > input.txt

When examined with a UTF-8-compatible tool, it looks like
<div><div>_</div>_<h1>abcdef_</h1>_</div><div></div>

I am trying to extract the part between _<h1> and _</h1>. I used the following program for gawk:
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 gawk -vIGNORECASE=1 '{match($0, /^.*_<h1>(.*)_<\/h1>.*$/,a); print a[1]}' input.txt

Question: why is a[1] empty for the combination of this particular program and this particular input? If I remove the IGNORECASE = 1 part or replace /^.*_<h1>(.*)_<\/h1>.*$/ with /_<h1>(.*)_<\/h1>/, the output is correct (because a[1] contains abcdef). But how can any of these changes affect the output in my situation?
My environment: Cygwin/MSYS2. gawk --version shows 5.1.0 or 5.2.2.

I cannot reproduce the problem here with GNU Awk 5.3.0. The output is the expected abcdef.

Neither do I, but OP's using Cygwin so it might be related to the regex engine of Windows.

BTW, why not use a XPath processor for this kind of task?

@Fravadona: I only need a scripting language that can read files making use of the user-defined record separators (where a record separator may be a regular expression), does not load the entire file into memory and is supported natively on Windows, so that the output depends only on the program version, not on what OS I am using. What language can be used as an alternative to gawk?

@lyricallywicked No, I mean that if you want to process HTML/XML then standard UNIX tools are prone to break with sightly harder cases. For what you describe awk is a good fit but you seem to have reached a bug here

I would just pipe it to sed -E 's,.*_<h1>(.*)_</h1>.*,\1,'. This: echo '3C6469763E3C6469763E5F3C2F6469763E5F3C68313E6162636465665F3C2F68313E5F3C2F6469763E3C6469763EF09F93853C2F6469763E0A' | xxd -r -p | sed -E 's,.*_<h1>(.*)_</h1>.*,\1,' returns abcdef

@EdMorton: Some issues related to multibyte characters (such as obtaining the correct number of code points in a string) can be worked around. But the issue I have described is particularly hard to solve because a multibyte character is outside of what must be captured by (.*)! And I cannot imagine why removing the IGNORECASE = 1 part or modifying the regex lead to the expected output.

@EdMorton: note that if IGNORECASE is set to 0, the output is empty too. It is only the absence of the flag that seems to solve the problem.

I created a bug report for this and your other related issue at https://mail.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2024-07/msg00000.html. Keep an eye on that to see what the gawk providers say about it, they usually respond within a few hours or a day at most.

GNU Awk is not "native" on Windows, by any sane definition of "native".

@tripleee not my area of expertise at all but see the gawk manual where it says "to build a native MS-Windows binary of gawk using the MinGW tools, type ‘make mingw32’" so maybe that's what the OP is referring to as their "native" target application and are just telling us how to reproduce their problem in cygwin since it's more common.

I'm arguing with the OP's logic. If they want something "native on Windows" that would be e.g. Notepad or win32.dll. If you have Cygwin, that's obviously a step in the direction of sanity, but also obviously not something Windows includes out of the box, or something Microsoft particularly condones. Thus, to my mind, any third-party scripting language which you can install with the normal Windows click-and-drool installer should be similarly acceptable. (You can have other reasons to prefer Cygwin, such as that what you already happened to install; but then say that instead.)

(... And if you wanted something Microsoft actually pretends to support in their usual lackadaisical way, these days I guess that would be WSL. And/or Powershell.)

@tripleee: <GNU Awk is not "native" on Windows, by any sane definition of "native">. Yes, I know, and that is why I asked about a language that is: 1. supported natively on Windows; 2. can be used as an alternative to GNU Awk. When I say “supported natively on Windows”, I mean a language that has an official site where anyone can download binaries (CLI) for Windows.

Then why not activate WSL2 where you will get Ubuntu with a sane version of Awk, as well as Python and Perl?

FYI feedback so far from the gawk maintainers is that this seems to be an issue with the cygwin and/or MSYS2 (git for Windows) port of gawk (and other GNU tools like sed and grep per my brief investigation). Waiting to hear from the gawk cygwin port maintainer now.

I would think [tag:powershell] could handle something like this easily. Not my area though.

Not an answer but too much info for a comment.
GNU sed and GNU grep on cygwin also behave oddly and are affected by their "ignore case" option and whether or not the end-of-string ($) marker is present in the regexp given the input you provided:
$ echo '3C6469763E3C6469763E5F3C2F6469763E5F3C68313E6162636465665F3C2F68313E5F3C2F6469763E3C6469763EF09F93853C2F6469763E0A' | xxd -r -p > file2

sed (GNU sed) 4.9:
$ LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 sed -E 's,^.*_<h1>(.*)_</h1>.*$,\1,' file2
abcdef
$

$ LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 sed -E 's,^.*_<h1>(.*)_</h1>.*$,\1,I' file2
<div><div>_</div>_<h1>abcdef_</h1>_</div><div></div>
$

$ LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 sed -E 's,^.*_<h1>(.*)_</h1>.*,\1,I' file2
abcdef▒</div>
$

grep (GNU grep) 3.11:
$ LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 grep -Eo '^.*_<h1>(.*)_</h1>.*$' file2
<div><div>_</div>_<h1>abcdef_</h1>_</div><div></div>
$

$ LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 grep -i -Eo '^.*_<h1>(.*)_</h1>.*$' file2
$

$ LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 grep -i -Eo '^.*_<h1>(.*)_</h1>.*' file2
<div><div>_</div>_<h1>abcdef_</h1>_</div><div>▒
$


Quick alternatives:

use _<h1> or _</h1> as the field separator, and print the 2nd field
$ gawk -F '_</?[hH]1>' '{print $2}' input.txt
abcdef

This is GNU awk 5.2.1

using pup which is like jq for html, and then manually removing the underscore
$ pup 'h1 text{}' < input.txt | sed 's/_$//'
abcdef



